# Array of variables to DataGridView table in Windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a class of public variables for use in a scoring system, but can't seem to find any easy way to print these all to different columns in a table.

The code for that class is below, you can see it's just a load of public arrays.

```
    {
        public static string[] playerName = new string[9];
        public static int[] playerTotalScore = new int[9];
        public static int[] playerEventScore = new int[9];
    }
```

and i want it to be output as a table, the first column showing the Names, the second column showing the total scores. How can I make it do this? As i can't seem to find any solution for this that fits my use case

Comment: Hello, what do you tried to output it ? It's not a space where somebody would write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long TotalScore { get; set; }
    public long EventScore { get; set; }
}
```

For Save:

```
Player player= new Player();
player.Name="player_name";
player.TotalScore =1200;
player.EventScore =123;

List<Player> players= new List<Player>();
players.add(player);
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can see it's just a load of public arrays.

In common with masoud's answer, I want to point out that we don't do this in OO languages:

```
//data store for 10 people
public string[] Names = new string[10];
public int[] Scores = new int[10];
public DateTime[] Birthdays = new DateTime[10];
```

We don't declare 10 arrays for the names, 10 for the score, 10 for the birthdays etc, and then have a "the data in the same position is from the same person:

```
Names[0] = "John";
Scores[0] = 99;
Birthdays[0] = new DateTime(1970,1,1);
```

---

When we want to keep data together, we make a class that represents it:

```
public class Person{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Score {get;set;}
  public DateTime Birthday {get;set;}
}
```

Then we can have an array of 10 of *those* if you want...

```
var people = new Person[10];
```

By the way, in modern C# we can use `record`s to quickly declare classes that hold data. They also have some other features that make them useful for things like being stored in dictionaries and compared to each other:

```
public record Person(string Name, int Score, DateTime Birthday) //roughly the same as above
```

---

So now you're down with this concept, you can populate a DataGridView quickly and easily.. Quick intro to DataTables:

A DataTable is a collection of DataRow. It also has a collection of DataColumn. Controls like DataGridview will use the DataColumns to know how many columns to draw, as well as using the rows. The DataTable is like the Person[10] above, and each DataRow is like an individual Person

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name"); //string, by default
dt.Columns.Add("Score", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Birthday", typeof(DateTime));
```

Then you fill the rows with data:

```
dt.Rows.Add("John", 90, new DateTime(1970,1,1));
dt.Rows.Add("Sarah", 78, new DateTime(1970,1,2));
dt.Rows.Add("Jane", 99, new DateTime(1970,1,3));
```

Then you tell the DataGridView to use it as a source of data:

```
peopleDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

---

A DataGridView can also work with, e.g. a `List<Person>`, so you could:

```
var ps = new List<Person>();
ps.Add(new Person{Name = "John", Score = 90, Birthday = DateTime.Now});

peopleDataGridView.DataSource = ps;
```

You might have to jiggle the columns around though; a DGV will create columns in the order of the `Columns` collection if it's using a datatable, but it might not create the columns in the same order as properties appear in the source code of a Person

Comment: thank you for the help. I'm pretty much brand new to C#, Winforms and OO programming in general so thank you.